# Combine dates in a column having the same id from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is the the table `DBtrans` which contains the same dates in different rows

```
+-------+-------+---------------------------+
|  ID   | dbID  |           pDate           |
+-------+-------+---------------------------+
| 14969 |  4982 |  2010-01-06 00:00:00.000  |
| 14970 |  4982 |  2010-01-13 00:00:00.000  |
| 14971 |  4982 |  2010-01-20 00:00:00.000  |
| 14972 |  4982 |  2010-01-27 00:00:00.000  |
+-------+-------+---------------------------+
```

while i have a bit how know related to SQL and what i tried yet is ..

```
select
    DailyBooking.ID
    ,CONCAT( pDate,' , ', pDate) AS InsDates
    ,InvNo
    ,AdCaption
    ,CONCAT( AdCM,'x', AdCOL) AS SIZE
    ,NetAmt
    ,RecievedAmount
From DailyBooking
inner join DBTrans
    on DailyBooking.ID  = DBTrans.dbID
ORDER BY DBTrans.dbID
```

Result:

[image]

in place of CONCAT column ! i want  the  all existing dates in DDtrans by this ID

Please Help

Comment: Add some sample table and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: i just want all dates of same id in place of CONCAT result's column @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be achieved using following query

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbtrans') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbtrans
GO

CREATE TABLE dbtrans
    (
    ID    INT NULL,
    dbID  INT NULL,
    pdate DATETIME NULL
    )
GO


INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (1, 4982, '2017-10-10')
GO
INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (2, 4982, '2017-10-11')
GO
INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (3, 4982, '2017-10-12')
GO
INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (4, 4982, '2017-10-13')
GO
INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (5, 4982, '2017-10-14')
GO
INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (6, 4982, '2017-10-15')
GO
INSERT INTO dbtrans (ID, dbID, pdate) VALUES (7, 4982, '2017-10-15')
GO
   select dbid,
    stuff((
    SELECT
    ',' + CONVERT(varchar(30), t.pdate, 120)

        from dbtrans  t
        where t.dbID = uk.dbID  
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as datelist
from dbtrans uk
group by dbid
```

Comment: i tried it but it is returning alot of dates in each row ! But i want the same dates which are in Dbtrans.pDate  apear in insDates column  while my other query is perfect for me

Comment: It is returning all the dates with a particular ID. I dont have exact database that you have so sort of not in position to see your actual data. Either you can put all of involved table with data so that I can try that here or you can use my given query and try to use it as template.

Comment: i used your given query sir but for example i have just 2 dates by some id but your query is returning alot of dates  !

Comment: actually data I created is having so many dates let me modify it for you

Comment: but i really like that STUFF function  could you please try to replace CONCAT pdates in my query as STUFF pdates   ? if you did i think that would be best and same as i want

Comment: no sir i didnt use your data i tried it on my one still that was returning huge amount of dates

Comment: Yes Apologies it is not working right I just realized that .Give me some time

Comment: That workes i have updated that in my query . thanks you so much. Up voted, marked.

Comment: the query becomes like   Select uk.ID, stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(30), t.pdate, 120) from DBTrans t where t.dbID = uk.ID for xml path('') ),1,1,'') as datelist, InvNo, AdCaption, CONCAT( AdCM,'x', AdCOL) AS SIZE, NetAmt, RecievedAmount From DailyBooking uk inner join DBTrans on uk.ID  = DBTrans.dbID ORDER BY DBTrans.dbID